# vue/comment-directive clear eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js

When I name the vue component `List.vue` I got the following error:
[image]

After I change the name to `Lists.vue`, the error disappears:
[image]

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable this validation set the "vue/comment-directive" to 0

["vue/comment-directive" to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNn87.png)

Comment: Don't share code as screenshots, paste as text and format the code please! [How to format your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because you are using a plural name in your component name. You just have to make it singular. That's all.